# How to load external javascript in sphinx-doc

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm extending the [basic](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html) theme from [sphinx-doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) and I notice the following code chunk inside basic theme `layout.html` `script` macro

```
{%- for scriptfile in script_files %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ pathto(scriptfile, 1) }}"></script>
{%- endfor %}
```

Does that mean I can add a `html_theme_options` like the following inside my `theme.conf`:

```
[options]
script_files =
```

and inside my `conf.py`, I add:

```
html_theme_options = {'script_files': '_static'}
```

However, with this set, the build is totally messed up and produced junk pages like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
     -->
   <!-- my js code but is automatically commented out-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Which part goes wrong? What should I do in order to load my own customized javascript? Thanks much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`script_files` is a template-internal variable. You cannot set it via `html_theme_options` (all theme variables have `theme_`as a prefix, see below).

The Sphinx docs explain [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#script_files) how to add additional scripts directly in the template files, via the `script_files` variable.

In case you regard it as important to define the additional scripts in your `conf.py`, proceed as follows:

1. Add the following line to your template's `layout.html`, for example below the `endblock` of the `DOCTYPE` definition:

`{% set script_files = script_files + theme_extra_scripts %}`

2. Define the theme variable `extra_scripts` and its default value in `theme.conf`:

`extra_scripts = []`

3. Override the variable in `conf.py`:

   ```
   html_theme_options = {
      'extra_scripts': ['_static/test.js']
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for the detailed explanation and the link to doc!